# Ratio of adjacent elements of vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I like to use diff(A) but this time i am looking for ratios between the elements of a vector.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
diff(A) = 1, 1, 1, 1
```

i am looking for a function like:

```
ratio(A) = 2, 1.5, 1.3333, 1.25
```

Comment: I like to use `diff` too :-)

Comment: If you determine to use `diff()` function, then you can type this `sign(A(1:end-1)) .* sign(A(2:end)) .* exp(diff(log(abs(A))))` longly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with simple indexing?  Chaining `exp`, `diff` then `log` seems to be quite heavy in overhead.  Simply have the numerator access elements starting from the second position to the end and divide element-wise by the denominator starting from the first position to the second-last position:

```
ratio = A(2:end) ./ A(1:end-1);
```

## Example Output

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5]

A =

     1     2     3     4     5

>> ratio = A(2:end) ./ A(1:end-1);
>> ratio

ratio =

    2.0000    1.5000    1.3333    1.2500
```

The above also works for both positive and negative values.

Comment: This simply meets the OP's need so +1.

Comment: Minus one for no `diff` :-P

Answer (score 5):

If `A` only contains positive elements, this solution works on multidimensional arrays:

```
exp(diff(log(abs(A))))
ans = 2, 1.5, 1.3333, 1.25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always loop over the elements of `A`

```
for i = 2:length(A)
    ratio(i-1) = A(i)/A(i-1) ;
end
```

Works for positive or negative values.